# Expectation of argument of a complex random variable.

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

Let $\xi$ be a complex random variable, assume that argument of $\xi$ is always between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Is next true?
$$ Earg(\xi) = arg(E\xi)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Consider $\xi$ which takes $1$ with probability $\frac12$, and $2i$ with probability $\frac12$.